# How to fetch the tables first 3 td values?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am doing data scrapping on the below table

```
<table width="100%" class="indexes">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Last</th>
         <th>Chg</th>
         <th>Chg %</th>
         <th>High</th>
         <th>Low</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="alt">
         <td class="indexes-arrow">
            <div class="arrow_positive"></div>
         </td>
         <td class="indexprice fleft positive">7,851.50</td>
         <td class="indexchange  fleft positive">+0.50</td>
         <td class="indexpercent  fleft positive">+0.01%</td>
         <td class="indexhigh fleft">7,888.50</td>
         <td class="indexlow fleft">7,818.00</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to fetch the first 3 td values that is 7,851.50 , +0.50 and +0.01%

I was tryng this way

```
  try
        {
            Document doc = null;
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://sgxnifty.org/")
            .timeout(10 * 1000).get();
            String tickerEl = doc.select("indexes tbody tr indexprice fleft positive").text();
            System.out.println(tickerEl);

     }
```

But it is coming empty , could you please let me know how to fetch the first 3 td values ??

could you please let me know how to resolve this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to select them by their classes

```
e1 = doc.select("td.indexprice").text();
e2 = doc.select("td.indexchange").text();
e3 = doc.select("td.indexpercent").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Here is even simpler since each of your tag has the following class `positive`

```
for (Element e : doc.getElementsByClass("positive")){
    System.out.println(e.text());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select using index also

```
e1 = doc.select("tr td:nth-child(2)").text();
e2 = doc.select("tr td:nth-child(3)").text();
e3 = doc.select("tr td:nth-child(4)").text();
```